# Python: pip tries to install to /bin directory

Tags: python, macos, pip

I installed python with `brew install python`

```
which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

my `PYTHONPATH` shows `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

However, when I try to install something with pip, it goes to the `/bin/` directory as shown below. I want things installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. How do I fix this?

```
pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
{....}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 384, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bin/virtualenv'



$ pip list
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (5.4.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)


$pip show setuptools
---
Name: setuptools
Version: 5.4.2
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg
Requires:
```

So pip already has the basic packages installed to site-packages. However, running the same exact pip to install virtualenv tries to install to /bin/.

Comment: /bin/virtualenv is a program used to create virtual envs later on. so it needs to be in /bin or /usr/bin or other place where bash will be able to find this executable.

Comment: Ok, I'll let that one go to /bin/virtualenv/ if that's where it's supposed to be. But now I try to install flask with pip (`pip install flask`) it installs it to /lib/python2.7/site-packages/, not /usr/bin/etc.... and when I do another `pip list`, it only shows the above. The same thing goes for `sudo pip install flask` and `pip list` after that. No flask appears.

Comment: Can you check the output of `brew doctor` and add everything python-related to your question?

Answer (score 6):

I was running into this same issue when trying to install virtualenv and flask. Turns out I had a `.pydistutils.cfg` file in my home directory. I remember placing this there not too long ago as a work around for installing something else. Once I removed this file, running `pip install` continued working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For me, there was a setup.cfg file with the following code

```py
[install]
prefix=
```

Removing the file fixed it for me.