# Can't do mkvirtualenv after updating macOS

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Today I updated my macOS to 10.14.5. After that, I can't do virtualenv like below.

How do I do `easy_install --user` during virtualenv is working?

I think some directory's permissions are broken by OS update...

Does anyone have suggestions?

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 proj_name
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/myname/proj_name/bin/python3.6
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/myname/proj_name/bin/python (you must use /Users/myname/proj_name/bin/python3.6)
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/myname/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

  Complete output from command /Users/myname/proj_name/bin/python3.6 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Looking in links: /Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Collecting wheel
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy_install.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

OSError: Command /Users/myname/proj_name/bin/python3.6 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I'm a bit confused, Do you want to activate a virtual environment or want to create one?

Comment: Have you tried to using `sudo` before the command?

Comment: @JayPatel want to create one

Comment: I don't think so it's happening due to OS update, I updated my os yesterday to the same version and I'm able to create a new environment without any problem!

Comment: @SangHuynh Yes, I tried. had similar error `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errno 13 Permission denied when running virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913862/errno-13-permission-denied-when-running-virtualenv)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError%3A+Errno+13+Permission+denied+lib

Comment: @phd Thank you. worked for me by your advice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465413/python-pip-tries-to-install-to-bin-directory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install a package to a system folder which you don't have permission to.
Try using 
`pip install --user virtualenv`, activate the virtualenv and run the command.

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: No. It is a stage before that. I can't do virtualenv and can't make folder